# Characteristic x-ray in energy spectrum

Tags: particle-physics, photons, nuclear-physics, radiation

Context: Monte Carlo simulation of a linear accelerator photon beam.

The energy spectrum for photons as calculated from the phase space
files found in [here](https://www-nds.iaea.org/phsp/photon/ELEKTA_Precise_6MV/) has a peak somewhere near $500\,\text{keV}$. The
characteristic x-rays on the other hand for tungsten fall roughly in
the range $60-70\,\text{keV}$. These photons represent a beam just after the flattening filter and just before the secondary collimators.

**Question 1**: Does anyone have any idea why the peak is so off? Or perhaps it
represents something entirely different?

**Question 2**: Since we are here, one more clarification: The term "characteristic x-rays" is used in *electrons* energy spectrum, right ? Isn't it wrong to use it the way I do here ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That could be a positron annihilation peak.

If the halo of your beam is scraping somewhere there will be a variety of interactions between the particles and matter. If it is an electron beam then many of the interactions will be electromagnetic showers which will produce (energy allowing) some $e^+$--$e^-$ pairs. When the positrons annihilate they will mostly produce pairs of 511 keV photons.

Comment: Nice idea; let me measure precisely the value of the peak!

Comment: Since this is MC, the other way to check is to look at the spectrum of particles produced. Positrons are diagnostic.

Comment: Yep, the peak is at $E=0.511\text{MeV}$. The explanation seems plausible. Thanks @dmckee!

Comment: Damn, your ESP is working well today ;-)

Comment: @JohnRennie More experience than superpowers. The smooth background rules out a lot of complicated scenarios and I have done enough medium and low energy work to have seen that peak *a lot*: it's sharpness and location are very (heh!) characteristic.